# How do I stop the path curve points from showing through the mesh?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

[image]

You see how the points are showing through the head? How do I stop that?

(Yes I know the hair looks terrible it's going to look better later I promise)

Comment: Object panel > Viewport Display > disable In Front?

Comment: There's no disable in front option

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I would love to but that website requires that I give them the right to use my work, so I can't, sorry.

Comment: you can use another platform like workupload, you can also modify your object